# null value in dynamic v-for with functional template refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

#### Situation

I am building a custom filtering component. This allows the user to apply `n` filters that are displayed with a `v-for` in the template. The user can update any value in the input fields or remove any of the filters afterwards.

#### Problem

After removing one of the filters, my array `itemRefs` got a `null` value as the last item.

#### Code (simplified)

```html
<script setup>
const filtersScope = $ref([])
const itemRefs = $ref([])

function addFilter () {
  filtersScope.push({ value: '' })
}

function removeFilter (idx) {
  filtersScope.splice(idx, 1)
  itemRefs.pop() // <- necessary? has no effect
  // validate and emit stuff
  console.log(itemRefs)
  // itemRefs got at least one null item
  // itemRefs = [null]
}

// assign the values from the input fields to work with it later on
function updateValue() {
  itemRefs.forEach((input, idx) => filtersScope[idx].value = input.value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(filter, idx) in filtersScope" :key="filter.id">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      @keyup="updateValue" 
      :ref="(input) => { itemRefs[idx] = input }" 
      :value="filter.value"
    >
    <button @click="removeFilter(idx)" v-text="'x'" />
  </div>
  <button @click="addFilter()" v-text="'add filter +'" />
</template>
```

#### >>> [Working demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

to reproduce:

1. add two filters
2. `itemRefs` got now the template refs as a reference, like: `[input, input]`
3. remove one filter, `itemRefs` now looks: `[input, null]`
4. remove the last filter, `itemRefs` now looks like: `[null]`

#### Question

Without the `itemRefs.pop()` I got the following error, after removing and applying new filters:

> Uncaught TypeError: input is null

With the `pop()` method I prevent a console error, but the `null`-value in `itemRefs` still remains.

How do I clean my template refs cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's up with using `$refs` inside `$refs` but it's clearly not working as one would expect.

However, you should never need nested `$refs`. When mutating data, mutate the outer `$refs`. Use `$computed` to get a simplified/focused angle/slice of that data.

Here's [a working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

```html
<script setup>
  const filtersScope = $ref([])
  const values = $computed(() => filtersScope.map(e => e.value))

  function addFilter() {
    filtersScope.push({ value: '' })
  }

  function removeFilter(idx) {
    filtersScope.splice(idx, 1);
    console.log(values)
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div v-for="(filter, idx) in filtersScope" :key="idx">
    <input type="text" 
           v-model="filtersScope[idx].value">
    <button @click="removeFilter(idx)" v-text="'x'" />
  </div>
  <button @click="addFilter()" v-text="'add filter +'" />
</template>
```

Comment: I tried that too, but still got a `null` value as a last item in `itemRefs`. Edit: What should I use as a `key`?

Comment: @wit, you're right, `$refs` inside v-for from other `$refs` seems borked. Maybe you should open a ticket on vue's repo. Meanwhile, I've suggested a different approach, which seems to work. It basically purposefully avoids nesting `$refs`. Cheers!

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: the [docs says](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs): `When the element is unmounted, the argument will be null. You can, of course, use a method instead of an inline function.`

Comment: @wit, which means the following would have produced the expected results, in your initial case: `:ref="(input) => (typeof input === 'string') && itemRefs.push(input)"`